# How can I find the code to support multiple plotting scales and X-axis on seperate panels using sizer routines?

Tags: python, matplotlib, toolkit

I have been using this code as a model to modify an application to support over 8 individual plots overlaid on the same axis and different scales on both sides.

I am having several problems so far.

1. Some Y labels are on the left and some are on the right. 2 or 3 are repeated (in error) on both sides (not all). It appears to be on the right side that overlays a repeat causing gibberish. One scale has numbers of the data that was plotted.
2. When the application is stopped, the black window (DOS prompt window) does not go away. I have a theory that there is two "canvas" blocks created, one by the call to create an instance using one call to create a canvas and another that creates a drawing area (and does not call it a canvas). The calls are as follows:

### set 1

```
myLOG_Fig = m_plt.figure(figsize=(3.0, 3.0), dpi=100)
self.myLOG_PlotCanvas = FigCanvas( panel, -1, myLOG_Fig )
```

### set 2

```
self.myLOG_HostAxes = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
```

Set 1 is required to present the `self.myLOG_PlotCanvas` to a `Sizer` placement routine which applies the image (drawing area canvas) on a panel (one of four panels). This set works great until I start the other plots (2 thru 8) to the canvas.

I found the solution (set 2) that uses the mpl Toolkit and AA to allow sharing of the X Axis and present more than 2 scales. by changing the code to allow for set 2 is where I noticed problems. The plots are accepted correctly to scale and color. The side scales almost look good (exception is repeats on the right) and I CANNOT CHANGE FONT size of the X-Axis labels and Y Axis labels. I could control the color and font size using set 1. Set 2 is unresponsive to changing character attributes. There are some other code that had to use the code required by set 2 (but I did not list it here). I personally do not think the two canvas drawing areas are the same and is one reason why the application does not die (black DOS window lingers around).

Is there newer up-to-date versions of matplotlib and mpl_toolkit code that connects the routines to one canvas drawing area? Is there some code that accomplishes my requirements (using sizers, etc) to produce an application with tabs and drawing areas on each tab?

Comment: Hi Wes, it is unclear to me at least (and judging by the lack of answers others as well) how to answer the myriad of questions and comments here. Try to detail a specific problem you are having and if possible provide some code that reproduces the error or an image.

In doing this you may solve some of your problems. One comment I can make is that for a single plot you should no have more than 2 labels on each axis (and then only if you use a twin axis). To distinguish between plots use a legend.

Comment: Wes, I would suggest breaking this question up into a bunch of questions, each of which addresses _one_ of your problems. Make sure to include the exact code you are using (even better if it is copy-and-pasteable so people can test your code!), a description of what it _is_ doing and what you _want_ it to do.

Comment: So far I have discovered the EXIT hanging issue.  So, one down ...

Comment: I am new to this and do not know how to respond to your inputs.  Give me a clue ....

Comment: I can click on the comment button all day but I think I am supposed to click something else to respond to you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Plot Generated from this code]

The following is my solution to my question (which I posted in 2013).  After searching for answers and solutions, I found several code snippets and pieced them together to make them work as a "team" ...
Some of the setup code is omitted to keep the listed code short.  The arrays for each 
y axis is one of the section omitted.

Code Snippet Follows:

class SubFrame_L(wx.Frame):
    """ SubFrame_L (2169 Lines)
        Sub-Frame class to create a frame that includes a Figure and Canvas
        for plotting an image to.
        Contains the following methods:

```
        BtnPlot      - button to invoke select a file to plot
        BtnClear     - button to clear canvas image
        BtnClose     - button to close instance of SubFrame_L
        BtnWordDoc   - button to Export image to Word Document file
        BtnPrint     - button to Export image to Word Document file & Print
        BtnClipboard - button to Export image to Clipboard

        DoPlot_SLIK_File   - select a file to plot, then transfers to canvas
        myLOG_DrawPlot     - processes file to plot data arrays.
        RePaintL_Canvas    - re-draws canvas after a canvas "clear" 
        Display_SLIK_Parms - displays Parameters read from file
        BtnClose_EVT       - event handler to clean up and close instance
        DblClick_EVT       - 
"""

    intDPI    = 100
    #
    fltFigX = 12.0
    fltFigY =  4.28

    self.myLOG_Fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=( fltFigX, fltFigY ), dpi=intDPI)

    self.myLOG_Fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.85)

    # New version of axes_grid1 with axisartist is recommended
    # host_subplot returns ax which is formed using plt.
    #
    # uses matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    #                               111 = rows,cols,subplot #
    self.x_AA_Axes_L = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
    #
    self.x_AA_Axes_L.axis["top"].set_visible( True )
    self.x_AA_Axes_L.set_axis_bgcolor( 'white' )    
    self.x_AA_Axes_L.set_autoscale_on( False   )      # <<< ONLY False works

    # *** ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Set X-AXIS for all Y-Scales
    self.x_AA_Axes_L.set_xlabel("Time (min)",  fontsize=8, color='red')


    # _________________________Offsets___________________________________
    # Y Label Axis offset from X-Axis
    right_Offset1 = 0                          # Temperature
    right_Offset2  =  right_Offset1 + 50       # Accelerometer
    right_Offset3  =  right_Offset2 + 50       # 

    left_offset1   = 0                         # Motor/Batt Voltage
    left_offset2   = left_offset1 - 50         # Motor Amps
    left_offset3   = left_offset2 - 20         # TBD
    # _________________________Offsets___________________________________


    # *** INIT *** SLIKPAK ***
    # +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Battery Voltage  (green) [left @ 0)  #-50]
    self.x_AA_Axes_L.set_ylabel("Battery Voltage", fontsize=8, color='green')
    self.x_AA_Axes_L.set_ylim(ymin=0.0,ymax=40.0)

    # +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Motor Current     (red) [left @ 0]
    self.axes_1_L = self.x_AA_Axes_L.twinx()    # Use subplot Base axis

    self.newFixedAxis_1_L = self.axes_1_L.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis


    self.axes_1_L.axis["left"] = self.newFixedAxis_1_L(loc="left",
                                        axes=self.axes_1_L,
                                        offset=(left_offset2, 0))

    # axis is shared by Batt and Mot - left is displayed, right is off
    self.axes_1_L.axis["right"].set_visible( False )

    self.axes_1_L.set_ylabel("force (g)/Motor Current (amps)", fontsize=8, color='red')
    self.axes_1_L.set_ylim( ymin=0.0, ymax=10.0 )

    # +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Temperature  (blue)
    self.axes_2_L = self.x_AA_Axes_L.twinx()

    self.newFixedAxis_2_L = self.axes_2_L.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis

    self.axes_2_L.axis["right"] = self.newFixedAxis_2_L(loc="right",
                                        axes=self.axes_2_L,
                                        offset=(right_Offset1, 0))

    # right is displayed, left is off
    self.axes_2_L.set_ylabel("Temperature", fontsize=8, color='blue')
    self.axes_2_L.set_ylim(ymin=0.0,ymax=300.0) #, size=8) #,fontsize=8, color='green' )



    # +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Accelerometer
    self.axes_3_L = self.x_AA_Axes_L.twinx()    # Use subplot Base axis

    self.newFixedAxis_3 = self.axes_3_L.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis

    self.axes_3_L.axis["right"] = self.newFixedAxis_3(loc="right",
                                        axes=self.axes_3_L,
                                        offset=(right_Offset2, 0))

    self.axes_3_L.set_ylabel("force [X(g),Y(o),Z(m)]", fontsize=8, color='green')
    self.axes_3_L.set_ylim(ymin=0.0,ymax=10.0)


    self.myLOG_FigCanvas = FigCanvas( self, -1, self.myLOG_Fig )  

    # *** Add special action buttons - pan, zoom, etc
    #
    self.NavToolBar_L = NavigationToolbar( self.myLOG_FigCanvas )
    #
    self.NavToolBar_L.Realize()

    # Start Main Box (Verticle Box)
    self.vMainBoxSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    # *** (v1) First, Add FigCanvas to Vertical Box
    self.vMainBoxSizer1.Add( self.myLOG_FigCanvas, proportion=1, border=5, \
                                    flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)

    # *** Start Horizontal Box
    self.hBoxSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    # *** (h1) Add Navigation Tool along with buttons to hBoxSizer (horizontal Box)
    self.hBoxSizer.Add( self.NavToolBar_L, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)

    self.btnPlot  = wx.Button( self, wx.NewId(), "Plot"  )
    self.btnClear = wx.Button( self, wx.NewId(), "Clear" )
    self.btnClose = wx.Button( self, wx.NewId(), "Close" )

    self.btnWordDoc   = wx.Button( self, wx.NewId(), "WordDoc" )
    self.btnPrint     = wx.Button( self, wx.NewId(), "Print" )
    self.btnClipboard = wx.Button( self, wx.NewId(), "Clipboard" )

    # *** (h2) Now, Add buttons to hBoxSizer (horizontal Box)
    self.hBoxSizer.Add( self.btnPlot,      proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
    self.hBoxSizer.Add( self.btnClear,     proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
    self.hBoxSizer.Add( self.btnClose,     proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
    self.hBoxSizer.Add( self.btnWordDoc,   proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
    self.hBoxSizer.Add( self.btnPrint,     proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
    self.hBoxSizer.Add( self.btnClipboard, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)

    # *** (v2) Add self.hBoxSizer to Verticla Box
    self.vMainBoxSizer1.Add( self.hBoxSizer )
    # *** Finalize self.vMainBoxSizer1
    self.SetSizer( self.vMainBoxSizer1 )

    # **** BIND Buttons to Handlers
    # This Canvas supports double-click to open another canvas window
    self.myLOG_FigCanvas.Bind( wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.DblClick_L_EVT )

    self.btnPlot.Bind(  wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.BtnPlot_L_EVT  )
    self.btnPlot.Enable( True )
    self.btnClear.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.BtnClearPlot_L_EVT )
    self.btnClear.Enable( False )
    # *** connect to "Close Button"
    self.btnClose.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.BtnClose_L_EVT )
    # *** Also connect to "EXIT Button" Strip
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.BtnClose_L_EVT)
    self.btnWordDoc.Bind(  wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.BtnWordDoc_L_EVT )
    self.btnWordDoc.Enable( False )
    self.btnPrint.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.BtnPrint_L_EVT )
    self.btnPrint.Enable( False )
    self.btnClipboard.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.BtnClipboard_L_EVT )
    self.btnClipboard.Enable( False )

    self.Layout()
```

End of code.
Start of plot example software code:

```
    try:
        # *** Battery Voltage (30 Volts) (green)
        # Number of Time entries must match number of VBatt entries
        self.x_AA_Axes_L.plot( self.fltArray_Time_L,
                                self.fltArray_VBatt_L, 
                linewidth=1, color=('green'))[0]       # [0] required !!!
    except:
        pass
    #
    try:
        # *** Phase               (1-4) [0-10](black)
        # Number of Time entries must match number of Phase entries
        self.axes_1_L.plot( self.fltArray_Time_L,
                            self.fltArray_Phase_L, linewidth=1,
                            color=('black'))[0]            # [0] required !!!
    except:
        pass
    #
    try:
        # *** BrushLess Motor Amps (3 Amps) [0-10](red)
        # Number of Time entries must match number of BrLsAmps entries
        self.axes_1_L.plot( self.fltArray_Time_L,
                            self.fltArray_BrLsAmps_L, linewidth=1,
                            color=('red'))[0]            # [0] required !!!
    except:
        pass
    #
    #
    try:
        # *** Temperature (72 degrees) (blue)
        # Number of Time entries must match number of Temp entries
        self.axes_2_L.plot( self.fltArray_Time_L,
                            self.fltArray_Temp_L, 
                linewidth=1, color=('blue'))[0]       # [0] required !!!
    except:
        pass
    #
    #
    #
    try:
        # *** Gx  Accelerometer    (g force)(0-10) (orange)      <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ORANGE
        #
        self.axes_3_L.plot( self.fltArray_Time_L,
                            self.fltArray_AccX_L, linewidth=1,
                            color=('orange'))[0]          # [0] required !!!
    except:
        pass
    #
    try:
        # *** Gy  Accelerometer    (g force)(0-10) (green)
        #
        self.axes_3_L.plot( self.fltArray_Time_L,
                            self.fltArray_AccY_L, linewidth=1,
                            color=('green'))[0]          # [0] required !!!
    except:
        pass
    #
    #
    try:
        # *** Gz  Accelerometer    (g force)(0-10) (magenta)
        #
        self.axes_3_L.plot( self.fltArray_Time_L,
                            self.fltArray_AccZ_L, linewidth=1,
                            color=('magenta'))[0]          # [0] required !!!
    except:
        pass
```

End of code

The interesting feature of the canvas window is it supports double-click which causes  a new (blank) window to appear.  Some of this code is omitted for space.

A file is selected that contains four to 7 columns of data.  Each column is presented to an array[] (each with a different name). A count is kept of the exact number of items inserted into the arrays.  An array_of_count[] will match each entry in the data arrays. and will indicate the time step (.0167 for this case) for each x axis step.  An example of the plot display has been uploaded for those interested.